# Как найти созданный .txt на устройстве? Android Studio

Tags: android

Повторил все с этой [статьи](https://metanit.com/java/android/13.1.php) один в один. Текст сохраняется, открывается, но найти на устройстве его не могу. Он как-то скрыт или что? Сам пакет приложения тоже обнаружить не получается. Ни на sd, ни во внутренней памяти. Подскажите, куда посмотреть, что дополнить в коде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В статье создаётся файл с флагом `MODE_PRIVATE`. Это означает, что с файлом ничего не смогут сделать без root прав. Расположение файла: /data/data//files/content.txt. В обычном файловом менеджере вы его конечно не увидите. В Root Explorer можно выйти в корень устройства, но в папку data вы без root прав не найдёте. Если вы хотите видеть файл без root прав в своём файловом менеджере, то измените флаг на MODE_PUBLIC

Answer (score 2):

В статье указан метод, который сохраняет txt файл в *кэше* приложения. По умолчанию в Android запрещено сохранять файлы приложений в корневом каталоге, но при указании двух строчек в  *AndroidManifest* можно читать и сохранять любые файлы.
P. S. Посмотрите в Интернете. А файл здесь (отрывок из статьи):

> В итоге после нажатия кнопки сохранения весь текст будет сохранен в файле /data/data/название_пакета/files/content.txt

Comment: Ну а подскажите, какие строчки то добавить? Я добавил вот это:
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

Не оно?

Comment: Да, оно) Именно)

Comment: Ну, я добавил это, но все равно не обнаруживаю искомого файлика( Может я не там ищу? Где эта data data? Есть Android, внутри Data, а там всякие пакеты других приложений. А в папочках заветные cache и files

Comment: Вы ищете правильно.

Comment: Я тогда совсем не понимаю. Нет моего пакета и все. Кстати у меня другое еще приложение есть с файлами настроек, все сохраняет и загружает, я даже не задумывался, но пакет тот тоже найти не могу на устройстве. Хотя пакеты от яндексов, дубльгисов всяких лежат, даже логи нашел почитал

Comment: Неа) Вы не там. Выйдите в главный корень. Там будет /data/data/<package>/files